# Python Tkinter Scale lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I was writing a simple color-picker script with python and tkinter, i have this code and it works:

```
from tkinter import *

color = [0,0,0]

def convert_color(color):
 return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(color[0],color[1],color[2])

def show_color(x,i):
 color[int(i)] = int(x)
 color_label.configure(bg=convert_color(color))

root = Tk()
color_label = Label(bg=convert_color(color),width=20)

rgb = [0,0,0]
for i in range(3):
 rgb[i] = Scale(orient='horizontal',from_=0,to=255,command=lambda x, y=i: 
 show_color(x,y))
 rgb[i].grid(row=i,column=0)

color_label.grid(row=3,column=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 mainloop()
```

I don't even know how I ended up with this but it works fine. I don't understand why I didn't specify x but I still need it and its value is updated when I slide the scale? The `show_color` function was with one parameter but it didn't work. I have looked up online but since I am a beginner I couldn't apply their explanations to my particular case. Also please let me know if anything else is having problem. BTW is there a way to use something like 'sender' for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scale provides x. When you give a function to the Scale widget, it calls that function with the current value.

I'll rewrite your code in a sane way so that maybe you will follow it better:

```
from tkinter import *

color = [0,0,0] # standard red, green, blue (RGB) color triplet

def convert_color(color):
    '''converts a list of 3 rgb colors to an html color code
    eg convert_color(255, 0, 0) -> "#FF0000
    '''
    return '#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(color[0],color[1],color[2])

def show_color(value, index):
    '''
    update one of the color triplet values
    index refers to the color. Index 0 is red, 1 is green, and 2 is blue
    value is the new value'''
    color[int(index)] = int(value) # update the global color triplet
    hex_code = convert_color(color) # convert it to hex code
    color_label.configure(bg=hex_code) #update the color of the label
    color_text.configure(text='RGB: {!r}\nHex code: {}'.format(color, hex_code)) # update the text

def update_red(value):
    show_color(value, 0)
def update_green(value):
    show_color(value, 1)
def update_blue(value):
    show_color(value, 2)

root = Tk()

red_slider = Scale(orient='horizontal',from_=0,to=255,command=update_red)
red_slider.grid(row=0,column=0)

green_slider = Scale(orient='horizontal',from_=0,to=255,command=update_green)
green_slider.grid(row=1,column=0)

blue_slider = Scale(orient='horizontal',from_=0,to=255,command=update_blue)
blue_slider.grid(row=2,column=0)

color_text = Label(justify=LEFT)
color_text.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=W)

color_label = Label(bg=convert_color(color),width=20)
color_label.grid(row=4,column=0)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you I understand now! Didn't know command could pass an argument. The argument will be always named 'x'? If I want to use it as a second argument how do I do it? It looks like it is the first argument by default.

Comment: The argument that the Scale command passes is not named; it's a "positional argument". It's always in the first position, and in my code I decided to name it "value". In your original code it was named "x". The Scale command only passes one argument, but if it had multiple you would make your def line match: `def(arg1, arg2)`. The number and type of arguments a function takes is known as it's "signature".